# Largest binary sequence with no more than two repeated subsequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

$A$ is an ordered sequence of elements $a_i = 0, 1$ containing no more than two adjacent repeated subsequences $[a_i, a_{i + k})$. What is the longest sequence $A$? Is it even finite?

For example, the subsequence $\{0\}$ is found three times in a row in $\{0, 0, 0\}$, and $\{1, 0\}$ is found in $\{\ldots, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, \cdots\}$ at least three times in a row. Therefore, both sequences are invalid.

As a simplification, if the number of allowed repeated subsequences is decreased to one, the sequences with the maximum cardinality under this new restriction are simply $\{0, 1, 0\}$ and $\{1, 0, 1\}$, each containing 3 elements.

Comment: This is confusing. 10 is not found in ...000... at all, and 01 and 10 are both repeated in 01010 and in 10101. Anyway, you *might* be interested in "cube-free sequences", about which much is known.

Comment: Edited for clarity. Also, thank you for catching my mistake with the simple example.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Now I'm almost certain you want to look up cube-free sequences, especially cube-free binary sequences, and in particular the Thue-Morse sequence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Gerry Myerson noted in the comments, you're probably interested in cube-free binary words.  There are many cube-free infinite binary words (words of infinite length).  In fact, there are [an infinite number of them](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61373/cube-free-infinite-binary-words/61376#61376).  Furthermore, there are [an uncountably infinite number of them](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61615/are-there-uncountably-many-cube-free-infinite-binary-words/61622#61622).

Comment: If you're interested in sequences with *no* repeated subsequences, then you might want to look at square-free words: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squarefree_word.  The field of study concerned with these is called combinatorics on words.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question! I was also surprised to see that there are an infinite number of squarefree words with an alphabet of three or more characters.

Answer (score 4):

A simple and unusually interesting example is the [Thue-Morse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue-Morse_sequence) sequence.  Let: 
$$\begin{align}
S_0 & = \langle 0\rangle \\
S_1 & = \langle 0, 1\rangle \\
S_2 & = \langle 0, 1, 1, 0\rangle \\
S_3 & = \langle 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1\rangle \\
S_4 & = \langle 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0\rangle \\
&\vdots
\end{align}$$

Where $S_{i+1}$ is formed by concatenating $S_i$ with its own inverse, which has 1 wherever $S_i$ has 0 and vice-versa. The Thue-Morse sequence is the "limit" of this process: The $i$th element of the Thue-Morse sequence is the same as the $i$th element of the first $S_n$ that is long enough to have an $i$th element.

$TM$ satisfies the following recurrence:

$$
\begin{align}
TM(0) & = 0 \\
TM(2n) & = TM(n) \\
TM(2n+1) & = 1-TM(n)
\end{align}
$$

This sequence $TM$ has the property that for any sequence $X$, $TM$ does *not* contain $XXX$.