# Infinite sequence of digits without consecutive repeating subsequenes

Tags: sequences-and-series, real-numbers, irrational-numbers

### Problem description:

Suppose we use a set of digits $\{0,1,2\}$ to form a sequence, for example
\begin{equation}
120210120102012102010210120212010\cdots 
\end{equation}
The length can be finite or infinite.

The sequence is invalid if there are two finite subsequences appears consecutively. For example, the following sequences are invalid 
\begin{equation}
0{\bf 11}\cdots, \quad 010{\bf 201\, 201 }\cdots 
\end{equation}
where the consecutive subsequences are highlighted.

**Question**: Does there exist a valid sequence of *infinite length*?
(a non-constructive proof is also acceptable; but a constructive one would be better.)

**One way to think about it:**

We can transform the sequence to a (base 3) real number, 
\begin{equation}
120\cdots \rightarrow 0.120\cdots 
\end{equation}
Then the only possible infinite sequence should be a irrational number. Irrational number has no period, which means the pattern will not repeat infinite many times, but may repeat finite many times. A famous example is the [Feynman point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_point),

> The Feynman point is a sequence of six 9s that begins at the 762nd
>   decimal place of the decimal representation of $\pi$.

So not all irrational number($\le 1$) are valid sequences.

I use a short program to do enumeration, but it quickly falls in exponential growth of candidates. I failed to come up with a contraction.

**Generalization:**

Can we take a larger set like $\{0,1,2,3, \cdots, n\}$? Can we relax the constraint to be three consecutive repetition or more?

**Motivation**

This problem origins from [threefold repetition rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281203/largest-binary-sequence-with-no-more-than-two-repeated-subsequences?rq=1) in chess,

> In chess and some other abstract strategy games, the threefold
>   repetition rule (also known as repetition of position) states that a
>   player can claim a draw if the same position occurs three times, or
>   will occur after their next move, with the same player to move. The
>   repeated positions do not need to occur in succession. The idea behind
>   the rule is that if the position occurs three times, no progress is
>   being made.

It reduces to the proposed problem if we modify the this rule to be "the same position occurs two times *with the same sequences of moves*".

Thanks for your help.

Edit: I find a related question: [Largest binary sequence with no more than two repeated subsequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281203/largest-binary-sequence-with-no-more-than-two-repeated-subsequences?rq=1)

Comment: "Not all irrational numbers are valid sequences" is quite an understatement. In fact, **almost all** real numbers (in the sense of Lebesgue measure) are irrational and "invalid".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are "valid" infinite sequences with three digits. They are called [square-free words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_word). Quoting the Wikipedia article:

> In combinatorics, a square-free word is a word (a sequence of characters) that does not contain any subword twice in a row.
>   
>   Thus a square-free word is one that avoids the pattern $XX.$
>   
>   One example of an infinite square-free word over an alphabet of size $3$ is the word over the alphabet $\{0,\pm1\}$ obtained by taking the first difference of the [Thue–Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence). That is, from the Thue–Morse sequence
>   $$0,\ 1,\ 1,\ 0,\ 1,\ 0,\ 0,\ 1,\ 1,\ 0,\ 0,\ 1,\ 0,\ 1,\ 1,\ 0,\dots$$
>   one forms a new sequence in which each term is the difference of two consecutive terms of the Thue–Morse sequence. The resulting square-free word is
>   $$1,\ 0,\ −1,\ 1,\ −1,\ 0,\ 1,\ 0,\ −1,\ 0,\ 1,\ −1,\ 1,\ 0,\ −1,\dots$$
>   (sequence [A029883](https://oeis.org/A029883) in OEIS).
>   
> Another example found by [John Leech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Leech_(mathematician)) is defined recursively over the alphabet $\{a,\ b,\ c\}.$ Let $w_1$ be any word starting with the letter $a$. Define the words $\{w_i \mid i \in \mathbb{N} \}$ recursively as follows: the word $w_{i+1}$ is obtained from $w_i$ by replacing each $a$ in $w_i$ with $abcbacbcabcba,$ each $b$ with $bcacbacabcacb,$ and each $c$ with $cabacbabcabac.$ It is possible to check that the sequence converges to the infinite square-free word
>   $$abcbacbcabcbabcacbacabcacbcabacbabcabacbcacbacabcacb\dots$$

Comment: Thanks! The "square free word" is the keyword I'm looking for.