# Is there an irrational number that the digits never repeat anywhere and have all 10 digits appear everywhere?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, real-numbers, irrational-numbers

Is there an irrational number that the digits never repeat anywhere and have all 10 digits appear everywhere?

let's look at one that doesn't work like $$\pi=3.141592653589793238462643383...$$ starting at the 23rd digit you get 33 so it fails another example of one that fails is $0.10102101023135791...$ even tho no digit ever repeats twice a pair of digits do $10,10$ and and here 5 digits in a row do $10102,10102$.

my question is there an irrational number such that all digits are used equally and no sequence of the digits repeat twice like this. $123547123547,8989,0909,182182,99,...$

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "have all 10 digits appear everywhere" ?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508866/infinite-sequence-of-digits-without-consecutive-repeating-subsequenes) is a closely related question.

Comment: so is there a irrational number where no sequence of digits repeat twice if you look at 0.1001011001101001... wouldn't work  because not all digits are there and 00,11,0110 repeats  @tristan

Comment: thanks @pregunton

Comment: The OP probably means that for every $n\ge2$, every word containing $2n$ consecutive digits is not a run of two identical words of length $n$.

Comment: While I don't have a proof at hand, it's very likely that such numbers are "rare" in the sense of having Lebesgue measure zero (equivalently, having 0 probability of being chosen at random in a uniform distribution on a bounded interval).

Comment: For $x$ chosen with uniform density from the interval $[0,1]$, for each positive integer $n$ the probability that digits number $2n$ and $2n+1$ are equal is $1/10$, and these are independent, so with probability $1$ there are infinitely many repeated digits.  Similarly, with probability $1$ there are infinitely many repeated $k$-tuples of digits for every $k$.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The sequence of digits you want is an [infinite square-free word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_word) on the alphabet 0123456789.

EDIT: Consider an infinite square-free word on the alphabet 012, which we know exists by Thule's construction.  Let the positions of $2$ in this word be $i_1, i_2, \ldots$: there must be infinitely many, otherwise after some point we would have an infinite square-free word on alphabet 01, which is impossible.
For each $k$, change the letter in position $i_k$ to $3$, $4$, \ldots $9$ or leave it as $2$ if $k \equiv 0, 1, \ldots, 7 \mod 8$ respectively.  The resulting infinite word is still square-free, and now has infinitely many of each of $0,1, \ldots, 9$.

Comment: This answer really doesn't go into the existence of a number whose decimal expansion matches such a word. It's not hard to show, but based on how OP's question is worded I suspect it might be nontrivial to OP.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged.  What happens when that link stops working? It would be well to pull the most relevant parts of that page into your answer.

Comment: Besides the other criticisms in comments, nothing in “infinite square-free word on the alphabet 0123456789” requires that all digits appear infinitely often.  E.g. an infinite square-free word from $\{0,2,1\}$ (which exists by Thule’s construction) can be viewed as over $\{0,…,9\}$, but doesn’t satisfy what the question asks for.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine That's true.  However, you can take such a word and change some of the infinitely many $2$'s to $3$'s, $4$'s, ..., $9$'s.  Well, maybe I should edit my answer to go into detail on that.