# Largest binary sequency with no repeated subsequences that have a fixed length

Tags: combinatorics

$A$ is an ordered sequence of elements $a_i=0,1$ containing no repeated sub-sequences [$a_i,a_{i+k}$).

**Example**

The sequence $(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)$ and a sub-sequence length $k=4$ produces the sub-sequences:

$(0, 1, 1, 0)$, $(1, 1, 0, 1)$, $(1, 0, 1, 0)$, $(0, 1, 0, 1)$, $(1, 0, 1, 1)$, $(0, 1, 1, 1)$, $(1, 1, 1, 0)$

Since all sub-sequences are unique, this sequence satisfies the condition.

**Counterexample**

The sequence $(1, 0, 1, 0, 1)$ and a sub-sequence length $k=3$ produces the sub-sequences:

$(1, 0, 1)$, $(0, 1, 0)$, $(1, 0, 1)$

The first and last sub-sequence is the same and therefore this sequence fails.

**Question**

Given $k$, what is the longest passing sequence that can be generated?

Is there a polynomial time algorithm to generate such a sequence?

**Related posts**

- [Largest binary sequence with no more than two repeated subsequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281203/largest-binary-sequence-with-no-more-than-two-repeated-subsequences?rq=1)
- [Infinite sequence of digits without consecutive repeating subsequenes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508866/infinite-sequence-of-digits-without-consecutive-repeating-subsequenes)

Comment: There are $2^k$ possible subsequences of length $k$. Therefore naturally the upper bound for the length of the longest passing sequence should be $2^k+k-1$. However I do not know whether it must exist.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence